# SuperLU: make: *** No rule to make target () .../Dropbox/Codes/

Tags: c, linear-algebra

I try to use the [SuperLU](https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu) library in my C project with Ubuntu.

After having followed the README instructions (see all my path below), the "make" doesn't work, and I read:

`make: *** No rule to make target '/home/allem/Dropbox/Codes/SuperLU/SuperLU/lib/libsuperlu_5.1.a', needed by 'stest'.  Stop.`

How can I fix this problem? I use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL-2) under Windows 10.

**My coding in the terminal:**

```
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem$ mkdir Solveurs
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem$ cd Solveurs/
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs$ git clone https://github.com/xiaoyeli/superlu.git
Cloning into 'superlu'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3542, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (176/176), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (50/50), done.
remote: Total 3542 (delta 147), reused 133 (delta 126), pack-reused 3366
Receiving objects: 100% (3542/3542), 5.08 MiB | 2.38 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3100/3100), done.
Updating files: 100% (745/745), done.
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs$ ls
superlu
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs$ cd superlu/
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs/superlu$ ls
CBLAS  CMakeLists.txt  DOC  DoxyConfig  EXAMPLE  FORTRAN  INSTALL  License.txt  MAKE_INC  MATLAB  Makefile  README  SRC  TESTING  cmake  make.inc.in  superlu.pc.in
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs/superlu$ cp MAKE_INC/make.linux make.inc
allem@LAPTOP-M5FU1POO:/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs/superlu$ make
```

**The final error after executing "make":**

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/allem/Solveurs/superlu/TESTING/MATGEN'
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sdrive.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sp_sconvert.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sgst01.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sgst02.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sgst04.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sgst07.c 
gcc -O3 -g -DAdd_ -I../SRC -c sp_ienv.c 
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/allem/Dropbox/Codes/SuperLU/SuperLU/lib/libsuperlu_5.1.a', needed by 'stest'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to want to compile from source? If you are unfamiliar with the toolchain, you are diving in at the deep end. If your needs are not extraordinary, probably prefer to install the existing binary package https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/kinetic/superlu

Comment: You are not following the package's build instructions correctly.  They instruct you to run `make` **from the top-level source directory**, not from the `CBLAS/` subdirectory.  There are other build configuration details that you might or might not need to attend to in your specific environment as well.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I ran first the make in the main file, then I tried separately in CBLAS, I forgot to mention that

Comment: @AlbertSchrödinberg, manually running `make` from the `CBLAS/` directory is not documented as part of the build procedure, and I do not expect it to be necessary.  If you have issues with executing the *documented* procedure then please present the details of that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the Ubuntu package instead of building the package yourself.
2. Use SuperLU 6.0 and CMake for building the library, it is easier then working around the issues in the provided Makefiles.
3. If you insist on using the Makefiles: In the file `MAKE_INC/make.linux` line 24, you have to adjust the path. Given is an example, you have to make it consistent with your system.

> SuperLUroot  = $(HOME)/Dropbox/Codes/SuperLU/SuperLU

Do you recognize the path from your error message? Change the paths of `SuperLUroot` and `SUPERLULIB` to suitable values and try again.